# How can I add keywords in my site without module?

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I'm using Drupal 7 and want to add meta tags in my theme. How can i do it without any module?

Comment: D7 doesn't come with any meta-tag functionality out of the box. You have to use a module.

Comment: Why getting (-) votes for this question? Funny boys... Thank you @Beebee

Comment: @Karmacoma Voting is usually based on the quality/relevancy of a question. The downvotes have likely been attracted as you haven't shown any research effort yourself, and because it's a very broad question. You also haven't explained why you won't use a module. Modules are the native way to extend Drupal's functionality; if you don't want to use them, you can't extend the functionality (well, you might be able to do some things at the theme layer but that's by-the-by)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a module is the preferred way, as in that way you don't need to edit a theme, or create a sub-theme to set meta tags.
The alternative would be changing the html.tpl.php template used from the theme, and add a call to a function present in its template.php file that returns the meta tags to add to the page.

There is one case where editing the theme being used, or sub-theming it, to add the meta tags would make sense: when the meta tags are very specific for the theme being used that they should not added to every theme used from the site.

I would also prefer using a module as I would not need to worry about updating the module for a new Drupal version, or writing the update functions.
If, viceversa, I need to be 100% sure there will be a module version for the next Drupal, I would write my own custom module, knowing that it's just me that can fix any security issues I would introduce in the code (which also mean I am left alone with finding any security issue).